# how to prevent a click event on a button if it is already processing a current request

Tags: jquery

I have implemented the following JQuery code

```
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
            alert(this.value);
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
        });
```

The problem with this code is that even if it is processing the code and someone again click the following button it again starts the execution.

How to prevent this thing ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'if it's processing the code'? The `addClass()` and `html()` methods are synchronous...?

Comment: `if(! $(this).hasClass('disabled')){ // your code }`

Comment: i am implementing a further code to send it to server for processing if server is taking 10 secs to process that request i.e the response i will get is after 10 secs. Now let's assume if user hac=d clicked that button 2 secs ago, now if the user again click the button after 4 secs i.e again sending the request to server. So how to stop it until the current request is processed ?

Comment: Sol 1. I think it is good solution to disable the button after click. Sol 2. Use boolean variable or switch to control the execution. Sol 3. Hide the button from display ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a flag?

```
var cartInProcess = false;
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
   if(cartInProcess == false){
       cartInProcess = true;
       alert(this.value);
       $(this).addClass('disabled');
       $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
      // do your processing
      cartInProcess = false;
   }else{
      alert("Please wait until the process finishes.");
   }
});
```

also you can use an attribute/data to check it instead of a global variable.

```
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
   if($(this).data("cartInProcess") == undefined || $(this).data("cartInProcess") == false){
       $(this).data("cartInProcess", true);
       alert(this.value);
       $(this).addClass('disabled');
       $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
      // do your processing
       $(this).data("cartInProcess", false);
   }else{
      alert("Please wait until the process finishes.");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as you're adding a `.disabled` class, you can add this to the very first line of your function:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
  return;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just disable the button and enable after processing.

```
 $(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                alert(this.value);
                $(this).addClass('disabled');
                $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a class to give disabled look, disable the button dynamically on click and enable it once the associated process is complete.

```
    $(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    //$(this).prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled'); //You can also add class if you want a customized look for disabled button.
    alert(this.value);
    $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the default button property `disabled`. You can disable the button until the process is going on. once completed you can again enable the button

to disable button

```
$(".btn-class").prop('disabled', true);
```

to enable button

```
$(".btn-class").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Have you checked the other answers before posting ?

Comment: oops, i should have reloaded the browser once before this :)